# Joomla pagination not working with alias url

Tags: joomla

I am working on joomla application. I am using SEO url for accessing application page, but some of page use alias. When I use pagination on alias pages it will give page not found error, but with SEO url it's working fine. Anybody have any suggestion for use pagination on joomla alias page.

SEO url: http://example.com/community/inbox
Alias url: http://example.com/inbox.html

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always use the non-url-safe notation in your code and add JRoute to it. This might look like this:

```
$link = JRoute::_(JURI::base()."index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&view=yourcomponent&Itemid=1&limitstart=20");
```

Above is a link to the second page in a component view, when displaying 20 items a page. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, it's is working fine with SEO URL.But when i use alias for page then pagination link not generate according alias page. It's generate like http://example.com/index.php?Itemid=107&amp;option=&amp;start=20 instead of http://example.com/inbox.html?start=20

Comment: Hello, I have solved this problem. I have created alias page  in menu and gave the external link on this alias page, now i give the jomsocial message layout link so, now pagination link working fine with this URL http://example.com/inbox.html?start=20  When i was using external url  link in menu that time seo URL was not working.